# Face shading differs for adjacent faces in same object

Tags: modeling, mesh, normals

Although it may seem that there are many posts related to that, I couldn't find any tangible solution to my problem, based on the following images, I couldn't get the smooth surface for bronze arm rest curved support. I have tried followings modifications w/o success. This discrepancy also affects the light map creation.

1. Edge splitting,
2. Recalulate Normals
3. Change Auto smooth to 30d

[image]

AFTER THE MODIFICATIONS 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! Thanks for asking a well-formed and thorough question! Don't forget to take the tour! http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your faces are triangles. Triangles are notoriously difficult to smooth-shade.

The short answer is that you need to convert your triangles to rectangles (quads).

To do that, you can take advantage of a built-in Blender tool: "Tris to Quads." Select all the faces that you're having trouble with. Then press <kbd>space</kbd> and type "tris to quads" and then select the matching command. This will automatically combine triangles into quads, where possible.

**But** this might not quite work the way you want it to. If it makes awkward quads, you might have to undo that and try something slightly different. Try changing to "face select mode" and then select two triangles that would make a tidy quad. Then press <kbd>space</kbd> to run the command again. You might have to this for each pair of triangles, but it'll make the shading much more smooth.

So, avoid triangles where you can. Use quads as often as possible.

Comment: Alt +J can do this faster when it must be repeated.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What does Alt-J do?

Comment: Hotkey for tris to quads.

Comment: Thanks in advance I just added the final images that I got after applying the tris to quads command( I don't have enough reputation to post more than 2 links so I deleteed the old ones). Regarding that I 'd like to know is this the  best that I can get in terms of smoothness from Blender, to achieve more refinement do I have to apply subdivision or am I still missing something fundamental?

Comment: Cool! I'd recommend rendering it because the real result will look better.

Comment: If you want more smoothing, you can add a subsurf modifier.

Comment: @Sonya You should probably replace one of those recent images with one of your original images with the triangles so it relates to your question.

Comment: I don't think Sonya has enough rep. I'll add it.

Comment: Although the original form of faces degenerate drastically, adding subsurface modifier yields better results, I'm afraid this the high res poly where I'm headind to. I wonder will I be exporting all this polygonal data if I want to use them in game engine. can't imagine what amount of data needs to processed by the game engine if that was the normal way of doing it.

Comment: No, you will not want to use a subsurf modifier for a game asset. You might want to add a few more splits manually, to smooth it out, but a subsurf will just be too much geo. There are some folks discussing a game in the chat lately. They might be willing to talk you through some more details. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm

Comment: I still have this problem even when I am using quads (I think?): http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70000/planes-rendered-into-two-triangles-of-different-colors