# Planes rendered into two triangles of different colors?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I defined some glossy planes by specifying the four vertices and vertex order for each. I rendered them in Cycles under an outdoor HDRI lighting. Strangely, some of the planes split into two triangles rendered in very different colors.

[image]

At first I thought it was due to surface normals, so I made sure the surface normals all point to the camera. However, the problem persists.

Why is it so, and how may I fix this? Many thanks!

Comment: Is your mesh smooth shaded? It looks like it is flat shaded ,so non planar quads will inevitably show visible sharp edge. Make your mesh smooth shaded, check *Auto Smooth* under *Mesh Data* in the *Properties Window* or add an *Edge Split* modifier. You may need to manually mark some edges as *Sharp* in *Edit Mode* if you have a mix of *Smooth* and *Flat* shaded areas in the same object.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks a lot! I just tried enabling `Auto Smooth` and am having a new (different) problem. I've updated the question. :-D

Comment: Try adding an *Edge Split Modifier*, if that isn't enough try marking smoothness-breaking edges as *Sharp* under edit mode. If it is still not enough, you may actually need more geometry by subdividing your mesh with a *Subsurf* modifier, though that will require adding a lot more control loops

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos many thanks again! As a newbie, `Edge Splitting` and `Sharp` sound like the opposite to what I want -- they sound like something that breaks the smoothness? Also, I am actually free to add more geometry to subdivide my mesh, and my computation resources allow for that too. In this case, I can just further subdivide my mesh, right? Does `subsurf` have more advantages than this? Thanks again!

Comment: Subsurf is non destructive, so it can be adjusted dynamically

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Just tried subsurf, but it is weirdly rounding my quad plane. Question updated -- any ideas? Huge thanks!

Comment: That is what subsurf does, it rounds things. If you have a mixed round/sharp geometry and don't want something to be rounded you have to add control loops. GO watch some tutorials https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBkwodrQq_4 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQZ5ZAldzu4

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thank you Sir! Your comments already solve my original problem. I guess it would be better for me to ask a new question on these followup questions, which I just did. Thanks and happy new year!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers: (TL;DR) This triangle effects can be removed by enabling `Auto Smooth` under mesh settings.

Credits to @DuarteFarrajotaRamos:

> Is your mesh smooth shaded? It looks like it is flat shaded ,so non
>   planar quads will inevitably show visible sharp edge. Make your mesh
>   smooth shaded, check Auto Smooth under Mesh Data in the Properties
>   Window or add an Edge Split modifier. You may need to manually mark
>   some edges as Sharp in Edit Mode if you have a mix of Smooth and Flat
>   shaded areas in the same object